# Expanded properties not working in an "if" segment

Tags: powershell, if-statement, iis

Title may not be very helpful but I couldn't explain more without the code so here is the script I'm trying to run:

```
$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors

(Get-Counter "\Process(w3wp*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples |
    Select-Object InstanceName,
                  @{ n = "CPU"; e = { [Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores),1) }} |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.CPU -gt 80) {
            Restart-Service -Name W3SVC
        }
    }
```

So the idea is to check for any iis processes that exceed 80% CPU usage and if so, restart the webservice. If I cut everything from `ForEach-Object` and down I get a list of my processes and the current usage of CPU in % in a list so that part works but I can't seem to get my `if` section to grab the CPU property.

Comment: Hi, your code works fine here. What does not behave how you want it to?

Comment: The reason I 'think' it's not working is because I swapped the `Restart-Service` to a simple `$_.CPU` and changed to `-gt 0` and I get nothing out of it. Just writing out `$_` before the `if` gives me the list but adding the CPU property doesn't seem to work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is indeed working and some of the tests have failed due to me trying to compare a single integer with processes that lists example of 0.4%.
Comparing with `-gt 0.0` was working a lot better.